# 透明なウィンドウに画像を表示させたい

Tags: c++, winapi

件名のとおり、透明なウィンドウに画像を表示させたいです。
以下のコードを実行すると画像すらもすべて表示されません。

また、CreateWindowEXの第一引数からWS_EX_LAYEREDを除くと、ウィンドウの表示位置に重なる部分が、拡大されてそのウィンドウに表示されてしまいます。（取れない）

どうしたらよいのでしょうか。プログラミング経験、知識はかなり浅いです...よろしくお願いします。

[image: 灰色のひし形が表示させた画像です。周りが拡大されています。]

**現状のソースコード:**

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <gdiplus.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "gdiplus.lib")

using namespace Gdiplus;

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow) {
    // GDI+の初期化
    GdiplusStartupInput gdiplusStartupInput;
    ULONG_PTR gdiplusToken;
    GdiplusStartup(&gdiplusToken, &gdiplusStartupInput, NULL);

    // ウィンドウクラスの登録
    WNDCLASS wc = { 0 };
    wc.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    wc.hInstance = hInstance;
    wc.lpszClassName = L"MyWindowClass";
    RegisterClass(&wc);

    // ウィンドウの作成
    HWND hwnd = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_LAYERED | WS_EX_TOPMOST | WS_EX_TRANSPARENT,
        L"MyWindowClass",
        L"Transparent Window with Image",
        WS_POPUP,
        100, 100, 512, 512,
        NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);

    // ウィンドウを表示
    ShowWindow(hwnd, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
    UpdateWindow(hwnd);

    // メッセージループ
    MSG msg;
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0)) {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    // GDI+の終了
    GdiplusShutdown(gdiplusToken);
    return msg.wParam;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    switch (message) {
    case WM_PAINT: {
        PAINTSTRUCT ps;
        HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);

        // 画像の読み込み
        Bitmap bitmap(L"image.png");

        if (bitmap.GetLastStatus() != Ok) {
            MessageBox(hwnd, L"Error was happend", L"Error", 0x00000005L);
        }        

        // ウィンドウのサイズに合わせて画像を描画
        Graphics graphics(hdc);
        graphics.DrawImage(&bitmap, 0, 0, bitmap.GetWidth(), bitmap.GetHeight());

        EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
        return 0;
    }
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return 0;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Win32APIのネイティブコードとは久しぶりですね(とほい目)。
それは置いといて、透明ウィンドウを作成するには2段階の手順が必要です。

(1)レイヤードなウィンドウを作成する。
(2)透明度を設定する。

ですね。提示のコードには(2)が含まれていないようです。
以下の様にしてみてください。完全に透明にすると見えないので半透明にしておきますね。

```
HWND hwnd = ::CreateWindowEx(
    WS_EX_LAYERED | WS_EX_TOPMOST | WS_EX_TRANSPARENT, // ・・・(1)
    L"MyWindowClass",
    L"Transparent Window with Image",
    WS_VISIBLE | WS_POPUP | WS_BORDER | WS_CAPTION,
    100, 100, 512, 512,
    NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);

::SetLayeredWindowAttributes( hwnd, RGB( 255, 255, 255), ( BYTE)128, LWA_ALPHA/* LWA_COLORKEY*/); // ・・・(2)
```

透明ウィンドウについては、MSの公式なドキュメントは
やや不親切なので試行錯誤が欠かせません。

Comment: 本当にありがとうございます。
私の理想していた動作が実現できました。
ところで、WinAPIって時代遅れなのでしょうか？
今の時代はコレ！みたいなものがあったらお教えいただけると幸いです。

Comment: Win32APIはOSの基幹I/F(C言語)なのでこれを使えば何でもできます。一方原始的すぎて高度なUIを作成するには手間がかかります。
それで、一時MFCを使って楽にやりましょうと言っていたのですが、しばらくすると全員C#で.NETにしましょうと言い出しました。
しかし一部のC/C++言語使いはそれを受け入れなかったのでC++/CLI、次にC++/CXという(魔)技術を用意しましたが説得できませんでした。レドモンドの連中によると、現在、C/C++系の推しは「C++/WinRT」らしいです。
C++から高度なUIライブラリがシームレスに使用できる上MFCも引き続き使用できます。めでたしめでたし。

Comment: 今だとGUI作成なら、C#でWPFでも使った方が作りやすいんじゃないですかね、GPU描画もしてくれるし。WinAPIは知識として知っていると役に立つ事も稀にありますが、API直接叩くのは保守性的にはあまり良くないです。（どうしてもC++でやりたいのであれば、別にとめませんが）https://atmarkit.itmedia.co.jp/ait/articles/1510/07/news025.html https://como-2.hatenadiary.org/entry/20110511/1305129674